# Writing the name chaya

Tags: names, shemos-sacred-names

In Hebrew, writing "chaya" with all its letters would result in spelling God's name "ya". Is this okay?

How should it be spelled? With a *'* instead of the hay? With a *'* between the yud and the hay? Any other ways?

Moreover, if it can be written fully, does it take the status of sheimos?

I first saw the custom to seperate the yud and the hay at chabad, but to me it seems weird due to the large number of other places I feel like I've seen yud and hay together with no issue.

Comment: What about Yehudah, Ovadiah, Yehoshua, Yehoram?

Comment: I have heard of the custom (Chabad IIRC) to separate the yud and the hey with an apostrophe or a hyphen

Comment: @Epicentre interesting, because I ask having seen the custom at chabad.

Comment: related: see [here](http://www.havabooks.co.il/sms.asp?cat=6) for a responsum from Rabbi Shlomo Aviner about writing and pronouncing the name Beit El. @NoachmiFrankfurt he mentions the names that you mention too

Comment: I thought we had this question already (about another name like _Chaya_), but cannot now find it.

Comment: @msh210 if you find it, do link to it. I'm curious what answers it's gotten.

Comment: @andrewmh20, FWIW (not much, probably), my non-Chabad rabbi wrote my name, which contains a Yud and Hey combination, with an apostrophe in place of the Hey in his inscription of a book he gave me on behalf of the Shul at my Bar Mitzvah a million years ago.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33584/sort-of-writing-the-name-of-god?rq=1

Comment: ...as Noach starts to point out, most Biblical Jewish names have a component that is one of the Names of G-d... just as the names of members of the other regional countries(Moab/Assyria/Babylon/etc) had names of their gods as components.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13271.

Comment: Within the set of names that could rationally be split into two meaningful words (one of them being a divine name), some subset of those names may very well carry some holy status (see [*P'sachim* 117a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=117&format=text), "דאמר רב ידידי-ה נחלק לשנים לפיכך ידיד חול י-ה קודש").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Excerpt from [this](http://www.kosherspirit.com/Article.asp?Issue=13&Article=160)

> The use of words and names like “Shmuel,” “Yeshaya,” and “Daniel” are
>   permitted, even though two of their letters represent Hashem’s name,
>   since the intended use is for a person’s name, not Hashem’s name. The
>   word “Bethel” can be written, as well as Beth-El in two words. Since
>   it is the name of a city, it does not matter how it is spelled.

See footnote (5) there. It is not linked, and they include a somewhat blurry photocopy, so I couldn't quite decipher what it says. Others are welcome to edit my answer to include it.

**Note**: The article is in English, so they transliterated the names. My understanding of the above quote is that they are saying that it's permissible to write the whole name in Hebrew letters without truncating or separating the letters, **b/c it's not considered shaimos**.

Related - There is no "Shaimos" involved in **saying** the name as is. My Rav relayed a story that on a date, the boy asks the girl her name, and she answers, "Bat-kah". He responds, "Nice to meet you. My name is "Kelikahu" ". It is ridiculous, no?

Comment: Footnote 5 in its entirety says עי' מבשנה הלכות ח"ו סי' קפ"ד

Comment: Another example of this sort of thing is at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29089/hyphenating-the-word-hashem

Comment: For some different opinions on the name of that city, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13271.

Comment: I still would like to know--can you write Chaya or not? 
If you do--does the paper have to be put in sheymos?

Comment: @SAH  FWIW, My Hebrew name is דניאל. In elementary school and high school, I used to write it דניא-ל since I thought I couldn't write God's name. A rebbi told me that it was unnecessary as I am not mentioning God's name as part of my name, and it has no "holiness" other than, of course, the "holiness" that my name identifies my being, which applies to every Jew. Logically, then, I would assume that if there is no holiness in the name, it is not "shaimos", and you can dispose of a paper that has such a name. I stopped counting how many test papers that had my name were torn up!

Comment: @SAH I'm puzzled as to why you are asking this question and why you put a bounty on this. I have bolded part of my previous answer, which states that it is not considered shaimos, thus, you are allowed to dispose of a paper that just has this name. Please read the linked article so that you can get the context and can confirm that I didn't misinterpret. If there is still something missing that doesn't answer your question, please specify what it is.

Comment: @DanF Yes, you're right. I guess I missed "Yeshaya." You get the bounty then!

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but I add that I have heard (forgive me for not remembering wherefrom) that when you are writing a personal name or a word that is not supposed to be a reference to Hashem's name, it is muttar to write it even if it contains letters relating to Hashem's name because the word and intention are not to refer to Hashem's name.

My Rav writes his name containing א-ל withOUT any break. Rav Ovadia Yosef signs his name containing י-ה withOUT any break between those letters either. 
[Signature of Rav Ovadia Yosef:](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=ovadia%20yosef%20signature&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNioCKo67WAhVIVrwKHeSgBb4Q_AUICigB&biw=824&bih=618)