# Can someone have the name Haleluka

Tags: names, shemos-sacred-names

Can someone’s Hebrew name be halleluka or would that be problematic?

Someone mentioned to me that it would be, but I couldn’t find any source for it.

Comment: Do you remember anything at all about the reason? Was it just the worry about the Shem?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49250/ . See also [P'sachim 117a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.117a?lang=bi).

Answer (score 4):

If they're combined as one name I don't see why it should be any different than say מיכאל, גבריאל, רפאל etc

Comment: Yeshaya (15 chars)

Comment: @RabbiKaii is it ever spelled without the ו at the end ?

Comment: Uriya, neriya, aviya, yedidya, gedaliya...

Comment: Obadya, Yirmeyah...

Comment: @Nahum yuppp ;)

Comment: @CuriousYid are you concurring with my answer or responding to my comment about ישעיה? If the latter are you saying it is or is not spelled w/o a ו? Because I ran a search and it doesn't look like it is ever spelled w/o it . . https://mg.alhatorah.org/Concordance/3470

Comment: @Nahum Regarding "ישעיה" w/o a 'ו': In the link you bring, I see 4 places it's brought w/o a ו at the end (you can see them by checking "וִישַׁעְיָה" and "יְשַׁעְיָה" in the "בחר צורות" side-panel): [Ezra 8:7](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Ezra/8.7#e0n6), [ibid. v. 19](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Ezra/8.19#e0n6), [Nechemyah 11:7](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Nechemyah/11.7#e0n6) and [Divrei_HaYamim I 3:21](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Divrei_HaYamim_I/3.21#e0n6).

Comment: @TamirEvan Good eye there Tamir however I'm pretty sure that Rabbi Kaii was only referring to the well known prophet ישעיהו בן אמוץ, those verses apparently refer to other folks . .

Answer (score 1):

I just came across a Rabbi that was actually named מהללאל הללויה!

He wrote a sefer on the Torah called קודש הלולים among other writings one of which was actually called ספר הללויה

https://www.sefaria.org/Shem_HaGedolim%2C_Maarekhet_Sefarim%2C_Letter_Kof.5.1?lang=bi&with=all